# Uninstalling Enterprise Libraries EntLib 5.0 Beta

Tags: enterprise-library

How is it possible to uninstall any of the Enterprise libraries?

There is no entry in the control panel to uninstall, there is no "Uninstall" on the menu.

I'm trying to install EntLib 5.0 and it fails because it doesn't like the EntLib 5 beta 2 on there.  I don't have the original msi and it is no longer available for download.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an entry in Control Panel to uninstall.  From the command prompt you can try:

```
MsiExec.exe /X{E530047D-5371-4AF1-AC60-7DC7A2DCBCCB}
```

Since it's not showing up in the control panel, I'm guessing the install is messed up so that might not work though.

Comment: Funny but I have 2 machines and none of the Enterprise Libraries are listed in the control panel "uninstall apps" on either.  But I ran cc cleanp and it shows up in there and I was able to uninstall it.